# How to figure out how many cans of two different sizes to be equal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Ok so I know this is an algebra problem, and I should be able to figure this one out, but I've been out of school way too long and can't remember how to do this.

I have 2 different cans of potted meat.  One is 3 ounces, and the other is 4.25 ounces.  I want to calculate how many cans of each it would take to be equal.  The answer would have to be integer, since the cans have to be whole.

I started with the following:

a = size of can a (3oz)

b = size of can b (4.25oz).

x = number of size a cans

y = number of size b cans

a*x = b*y

3x = 4.25y

but now I'm stuck and can't remember for the life of me where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x$ and $y$ have to be integers, the first thing is to figure out how to get an integer on the RH side of the equation. Obviously you need to multiply 4.25 * 4, so $y$ needs to be a multiple of 4. So now we have $3x = 4.25*4z = 17z$ for some $z$. Since 3 and 17 have no common divisors (they are both prime), the smallest solution is going to be $x = 17, z = 3$, so $y = 12$.

Comment: Ok, so I'm a little confused on the z variable added in. So I figured out the answer then is 17 cans of "a" and 12 cans of "b".  I'm just having trouble now getting the system of equations down.  I know this seems rather pointless in a way, but I used to be able to do this stuff in my sleep back in high school. I'd like to at least remember it again.

Comment: This isn't strictly an algebra problem. It is number theory. Your equation was alright, but it was only one equation in terms of two variables, so all it could ever tell you was, if you knew the value of one of the variables, what would the other one be. The only way to go further was to examine what the restriction to integer values tells us. And the first thing is that since $3x$ is integer, so must be $4.25y$, which means that $y$ has to be a multiple fo $4$, so I set $y = 4z$, and replaced that in your original equation.

Comment: I see. so is there a way to express it in a set of equations?

Comment: No. There is only one equation. That is why it is a number theory problem, not an algebra problem.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  Now I wish I'd kept up on my math after I got out of school.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to express 4.25 as an improper fraction: $\frac{17}{4}$.  If you translate the ratio between the cans' weights, $3 : \frac{17}{4}$, to lowest terms, you get $12:17$.  The numbers of the two kinds of can must be in this ratio, $12n$ heavy cans to $17n$ light cans, for some integer $n$.

(Fortunately this is a rational number; if it were not, there would be no solution.)